# Output shape of a convolutional filter

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Below I have the following architecture. I have input image $28\times 28$ and the following convolutional and pooling layers:

$28\times 28 -> 32 (3\times 3) kernels -> (2\times 2) pooling -> 64 (3\times 3) kernels-> (2\times 2) pooling$

To my understanding:

First output: after applying $32 (3\times 3) kernels$ is $28-3 + 1 = 26$ (for both width and height), so we will have $32 (26 \times 26)$ output.

Second output: after applying $(2\times 2) pooling$ on the first output is $o=\lfloor \frac{26}{2} \rfloor =13$ (for both width and height), so we will have $32 (13 \times 13)$ output.

Third output: after applying $64 (3\times 3) kernels$ on the second output (for both width and height), so we will have $64 (11 \times 11)$ output. But I am not sure why we have $64 (11 \times 11)$ output given that we apply $64 (11 \times 11)$ on each $32 (13 \times 13)$ output, so we should have $64 \times 32 (11 \times 11)$, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolution operation in neural networks also has a channel dimension. The kernels will always have a channel dimension equal to the input channel dimension. The input and weight channel dimension are multiplied and accumulated as well, thus disappear.

First layer: `28 x 28` input image with only `1` channel is filtered with 32 `3 x 3` kernels. 32 is also referred as output feature maps (i.e. output channels). So, the output will be `26 x 26` image as you said, but with `32` channels.

Second layer: this is pooling, and as you mentioned, the output `13 x 13` images with `32` channels.

Third layer: There are 64 `3 x 3` kernels, so the number of output channels is `64`. It's not stated, but the kernel also has a hidden channel dimension which must be equal to the input channel dimension.  Thus each kernel is of `3 x 3 x 32` shape (channels last notation). The channel dimension is also accumulated while sliding the kernel, so it disappears. There are 64 kernels, then, the output of this layer is `11 x 11` images with `64` channels.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how 64 (3 x 3) kernels are applied to the 32 (13×13) output from the previous step? Is it that we apply 3D matrix of shape 3x3x64 to the output 13x13x32? But since 64>32, then there will be nothing to multiply against after 32 from the output as 64 is larger.

Comment: Assuming channels last notation, the input is `13 x 13 x 32`, and the kernel is `64 x 3 x 3 x 32`. The convolution is done on 3D shapes, although it's called Conv2D. It's a special case, where all the input channels disappear.

Comment: Thank you. I am still confused about this part. Does that mean that I apply each of the 64 3x3 filters on each of the 13x13x32 images from the output from the second step please? For example, I apply each of the 64 3x3 filters on each 13x13 out of 32 imagers from the second step once? If that is the case, we should get for each image 64 (3x3), which means as I understand we have 64 x32 x 11x11

Comment: When doing the convolution, i.e. sliding the kernel, you don't just multiply 9 (i.e. 3x3) input and kernel pixels and sum, you also multiply the channels as well, so, for a single kernel+input dot product, we have kH x kW x C multiply accumulates, in this case 3 x 3 x 32. You can think of input channels as RGB values and at the end of the convolution, they are weighted averaged using kernel coefs. Each kernel has kH x kW x C coefficients, not kH x kW. You may want to look at tensorflow's documentation: tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d